# CDH Manager in Azure VM. Can't reach CDH Manager's Web portal

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, rhel, cloudera-cdh

I provisioned myself a RHEL VM in Azure and installed CloudEra CDH manager in it. When I try to access its web portal via port 7180, I can't reach this and I'm getting page can't be reached error.

I tried TELNET and this connection is not established.

I checked in the Azure Management Portal and added a rule to port 7180 to allow traffic from any source.Yet, I'm still unsuccessful.

What can I do to get it corrected.

Comment: What is the result `netstat -ant|grep 7180`? The service is running?

Comment: I suggest you could check log in `/var/log/cloudera-manager-installer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check as the following steps:

1.Using `netstat -ant|grep 7180`, please ensure the service is running and runs on port 7180.

2.If the service is not running, you could check log in `/var/log/cloudera-manager-installer`.

3.Open port 7180 on VM's firewall.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7180/tcp --permanent
```

Note: It seems you have open port 7180 on Azure NSG, I suggest you could check again.

Comment: Hi, does it work now? According to your description, it seems the service is not running or you don't open port on VM's firewall(only open port 22 by default).

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your reply ...  

        [vignesh@system1 cloudera-manager-installer]$ netstat -ant|grep 7180
        tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7180            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Yes, the service is started as per log and I can see the service is running in ps -ef.

I've opened the port on the VM Firewall and Port 7180 is open in Azure NSG.

Comment: Could you share your public IP? What is the result `curl 127.0.0.1:7180` on your VM?

Comment: This is what I did  .. I opened port 7180 in VM .. and tweaked firewall in Azure NSG ... Restarted my VM ..  Now its working ,,